# Plumbing drain to connect to main sewer outlet

Tags: plumbing

I'm in the process of adding an outdoor toilet and sink to the rear of my house and would like to connect the drain to the main sewer line at the back of the house.

Below is a photo of the existing setup to which I would like to connect the additional drain.

Where would you recommend making the connection? My main concern is backflow into the drain that I'm going to add.

[image]

Comment: What's coming in via the air gap setup?

Comment: This doesn't look like a main connection but a smaller line for the air conditioner drain connection.

Comment: You know the whole toilet has to be higher than the point you tie into the sewer, right?  So you'll have to dig into the ground to tie into t a sewer or the toilet will have to be elevated.

Comment: That's a combination wye which is wrong for a p-trap.  Switch it to a sanitary tee while you are working on this.  That is also a 2" line you can't add a toilet to a 2" line.  I'd guess the air gapped thing is an output of a sump well.

Comment: It actually is the main connection. It's a 4 bedroom house from 1970 and everything comes out the 2'' pipe on the right and connects to the main 4'' sewer line. I'm going to raise the toilet so it is higher than the tie in connection. One option would be to connect directly on top of the 4'' sewer pipe on the left but the toilet would have to be much higher. I was hoping to find a way to connect it to a lower point so I don't need to raise the toilet as much.

Comment: Er, no. No it doesn't. Even if you have an ejector pump which uses a 2" output line, there's no way you have an air gap in your poop pipe, nor would it have a trap like that. Or do I misunderstand your explanation?

Comment: On second thought you are probably right. The toilet outlet can't be here. Only option is to connect the toilet to the 4'' sewer pipe directly then I believe.

Comment: I agree with Isherwood and jack that might be some kind of cluster added to a clean out but nothing less than 3 “ would be code and back in the 70’s I only remember 4” unless an engineered system with a pit and pump and everything to the pit would still be 3 or 4”. You might dig down to find the main 4” line tap into it there and fix that mess.

Comment: The pipe of the left with the screw top is 4''. Would it be ok to remove screw top and connect 4'' direction to that?